# Improving the quality of pseudo-randomly generated uncorrelated unit normals

Tags: normal-distribution

Let's say I want to generate $N$ sequences $p_j$, where $j = 1,\ldots,N$.  Each sequence has a length of $M$.  I want $\mathbb{E}[ p_j ] \to 0$ and $\text{corr}(p_j, p_k) \to \delta_{j, k}$ as $M \to +\infty$.

In practice, I can generate an $M \times N$ matrix of i.i.d. unit normals.  For example, in MATLAB, `Z = randn(M, N)`.  Then I get $p_j$ from the $j$-th column of $Z$.

For a finite value of $M$, the sample mean $\mathbb{E}[ p_j ] \neq 0$, but I can "fix" the problem if I remove the sample mean by working with $q_j = p_j - \mathbb{E}[ p_j ]$.

My question is -- how do I continue to improve my sequences, so that I get the 2nd-order moments I want, i.e., $\text{corr}(q_j, q_k) = \delta_{j,k}$ even when $M$ is finite?

Comment: Note that in removing the means you have made your sequences not quite iid: values now have a slight negative correlation.  In standardizing the covariance matrix you will exacerbate that somewhat. There is an inevitable trade-off between maintaining independence *within* each sequence and no correlation *between* sequences.  If that's ok with you, then the next question is one of computational efficiency: although there are readily available solutions (e.g., SVD), they may start to founder as $M$ and $N$ grow large.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.  If $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ but we want to generate $X$ such that its mean is $\mu$ and covariance matrix is $C$, we decompose $C = L L^T$, and let $X = L Z + \mu$.

Now we just need to carry out the reverse operations.